# How to activate rpcbind service in CentOS installed on virtual box?

Tags: centos, nfs

I installed CentOS7 on Virtualbox. I have installed port map using `sudo yum install portmap` and then tried to enable it with `service rpcbind start` however I can not enable the service. I tried rebooting and entering following codes but nothing happened:

```
[hadi@localhost ~]$ systemctl enable rpcbind.socket
[hadi@localhost ~]$ systemctl restart rpcbind.service
Job for rpcbind.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rpcbind.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I appreciate your suggestions

if you need the status of rpcbind:

```
    Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l rpcbind.service
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-06-17 18:32:07 IRDT; 32s ago
  Process: 4382 ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -w $RPCBIND_ARGS (code=exited, status=127)

Jun 17 18:32:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting RPC bind service...
Jun 17 18:32:07 localhost.localdomain rpcbind[4382]: /sbin/rpcbind: symbol lookup error: /sbin/rpcbind: undefined symbol: libtirpc_set_debug
Jun 17 18:32:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rpcbind.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jun 17 18:32:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RPC bind service.
Jun 17 18:32:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rpcbind.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 18:32:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rpcbind.service failed.
```

Comment: The full output, with -l, would help a bunch.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I updated the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this bug report:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1396291

> rpcbind can fail to start after updating to the 7.3 rpcbind package
>   from an earlier version, if the libtirpc package is not updated as
>   well.
>   
>   [...]
>   
>   Updating the libtirpc package fixes this issue.

In other words:
 
update the `libtirpc` package and then restart `rpcbind`.

Comment: Using 'sudo yum upgrade' fixed that.
thank you